# Google Maps V3 2017 still slow when adding markers/circles

Tags: android, google-maps

Google Maps API on Android still has an issue where it takes a long time to load many markers/circles. In my case I am drawing 130+ circles with Lat/Lng to the Google Map. This process takes 20s to complete. Here is the code for adding the circles which is called after `@Override public void onMapLoaded`:

```
List<Crime> crimes = mCrimeManager.getListOfCrimes();
Log.d("CRIME SIZE TAG", "   " + crimes.size());

for(Crime crime:crimes)
{
    if(!(getLocationOfCrime(crime) == null)) 
    {
        Circle circle = googleMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
               .clickable(true)
                .radius(5)
                .center(getLocationOfCrime(crime)));
        circle.setTag(crime);
```

I know that this is the issue because removing this code causes everything to run smoothly with no delay.

I have looked at multiple questions in the past but most are using clustering or loading only with a certain range which can not be applied to my case. I have tried running this on AsyncTask with a `runOnUiThread();` in `doInBackground();` but that still yields same performance.

Comment: Okay I figured out the actual issue. It seems that geolocating, getting lat/lng of a String location is actually the problem not adding the markers. Any suggestions on how to speed this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay guys here is the solution. It turns out adding the markers is not processor intensive. Geolocating is the issue. If you are running into this issue it is because you are geolocating on the main thread. The way I fixed my problem was putting geolocation calculations on AsyncTask (`doInBackground();`) then on `onPostExecute` adding the markers.

Still there is an issue where geolocation takes time(UI running smoothly but no markers), but this is a Google Maps API issue. I sorta fixed this by doing the geolocation once at startup then storing everything into SQLiteDataBase then reading in from there after each time.

Thanks